# Virto Commerce and Azure website template- Virto Commerce Manager LocalizationModule error version 1.11.0.0

Tags: azure, deployment, e-commerce, virtocommerce

I have an error trying to access my new site I created in Azure. I cannot upgrade. I have a link from the Virto /admin page to direct me to http://mywebsiteurlhere.azurewebsites.net/App_Admin/VirtoCommerce.application?storeurl=http://mywebsiteurlhere.azurewebsites.net/
Is there anything else I should look at? SQL local is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

```
Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializeException: An exception occurred while initializing module 'LocalizationModule'. 
    - The exception message was: An error occurred while processing this request.
    - The Assembly that the module was trying to be loaded from was:VirtoCommerce, Version=1.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception occurred while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help locate the root cause of the problem. 
   ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 86.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String&amp; keyname, String&amp; keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.Services.Caching.MetadataCache`1.MetadataCacheKey..ctor(Type serviceType, ObjectContext dataContextInstance)
   at System.Data.Services.Caching.MetadataCache`1.TryLookup(Type serviceType, Object dataContextInstance)
   at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata(Boolean skipServiceOperations)
   at System.Data.Services.Providers.EntityFrameworkDataServiceProvider2`1..ctor(DataServiceProviderArgs args)
   at VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Data.Infrastructure.DServiceBase`1.CreateDataSource()
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateDataSourceInstance()
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider&amp; metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider&amp; queryProviderInstance, Object&amp; dataSourceInstance, Boolean&amp; isInternallyCreatedProvider)
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider()
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody)
   at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton[TElement](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at VirtoCommerce.ManagementClient.Localization.LocalizationModule.RegisterViewsAndServices()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at VirtoCommerce.ManagementClient.Security.SecurityModule.<>c__DisplayClass4.<>c__DisplayClass7.<Initialize>b__3()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: Is your website currently running? If so what is the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seems to be a problem with connection string. Is your website currently running smoothly?

Similar problem described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/10/30/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specification-starting-at-index.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Azure shutdown my subscription trial and I am working with them to reactivate it. Once that's done, I will do a clean install to make sure 100% installed correctly. I will keep everyone posted.

Comment: Still no luck. I am having tons of issues running this.

Comment: Yea, it was the connection string. My password had an equals operator in it, which broke the connection string.